# Changing Express gateway config in runtime

Tags: config, express-gateway

I want to know if we can change the remote express gateway config from some other service(Might or might not be behind the gateway). Is there an API exposed for admins, to enable changing config without having to change the docker image of eg?

Our use case is we have an infrastructure based on tenants and want to change the config in run time without having container restarts or image changes. The documentation says config changes will be a hot reloaded.

If the above is not possible can you suggest what is the best alternative to change files in a remote docker container from other service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [Express Gateway Admin API](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/admin/) has endpoints to add, remove, list, or change the following entities:

- [Policies](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/admin/policies/)
- [Service Endpoints](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/admin/service-endpoints/)
- [API Endpoints](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/admin/api-endpoints/)
- [Pipelines](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/admin/pipelines/)

I have not used them, but the documentation suggests that they update the gateway.config.yaml configuration file.